# About Date Formatting

Tags: java, android, date

I m trying to append date separator `'/'` automatically after dd and mm whenever user entering the dd and mm values but the problem is after appending the date separator I cant remove the separator neither pressing backspace nor by pressing delete

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
    if(s.length() == 2)
    {
        lst_date = let_date.getText().toString();
        lst_date = lst_date.concat("/");
        let_date.setText(lst_date.toString());
        Log.v(TAG,"VAlue is s:"+ s.length() +" date:"+ lst_date);
        let_date.setSelection(let_date.length());
    }
    else if(s.length() == 5)
    {
        lst_date = let_date.getText().toString();
        lst_date = lst_date + "/";
        let_date.setText(lst_date);

        let_date.setText(lst_date.toString());
        Log.v(TAG,"VAlue is s:"+ s.length() +" date:"+ lst_date);

        let_date.setSelection(let_date.length());
    }

}
```

Comment: which error code did you get? the logcat output will not be bad

Comment: all other characters are removable?

Comment: yup all other character are removable except that date separator '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my guess. It's not that you can't remove '/' but rather it gets added back by your method right after it just got deleted. Namely, when you hit backspace, it removes '/', then `afterTextChanged()` gets called and sees that s.length() is either 2 or 5, resulting '/' to be added back.